# How to convert nvarchar to bigint in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, casting

Example Case 
TableA contains values like name,id,etc 
TableB contains uniqueName,id,etc

Now what i want is to get the uniqueName of those ids who are present in TableA so ids are compared

```
SELECT * FROM  TableA INNER JOIN
TableB ON TableA.para1= TableB.para2
WHERE (TableA.paraX= @paraX)
```

I have **para2** in **tableB** as `nvarchar(MAX)` and **para1** in **tableA** as `bigint`

I cant change the datatypes now.. 
I have tried few things

```
like `CAST(TableB.para2 AS bigint)`
```

And

```
convert(bigint, TableB.para2)
```

But there are also cases in which ids could not be found shud i have any such condition like null check

Wud that give error or datatype match ?

Comment: Did you try doing that? What result did you get?

Comment: What was the result of your tries? Did you get any error message?

Comment: Error converting datatype nvarchar to bigint

Comment: this error is coming with the trials and also without trials ..so i am bit confused if the trials are working or not